# how can I allow access to AWS ec2 IP with a specific port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I want to allow access to the admin panel hosted in AWS ec2 only through a specific port like http://65.0.177.9:49555/,I have tried in the security group to set the port range but not successful

Comment: What do you mean by "not successful"? Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you saying that requests coming from `65.0.177.9` are permitted to send traffic into the instance on port 49555? Please show us your Security Group configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At server level, there is Security Group, but assuming you use VPC, there is also Network Access Control which might be blocking such exotic port.

Please also remember to open whichever web server is running on that server to accept connections on that port.

And finally, make sure local firewall is not blocking it.